# display weekly summaries from user entered dates in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a project for where I am supposed to create an automated spreadsheet.
The first sheet takes the person's manually entered data. For example, let's say the person is entering an X amount of whatever he received on XX/XX/XX date (use text to columns in excel, then delimited, then click tab and space and finish).

```
       11/19/2015   11/20/2015  11/25/2015  11/30/15    1/2/2016
Apples    4             5           2           7           1
Bananas   6             4           5           7           3
Oranges   3             0           4           0           0
```

Now, this is all user entered data. From this user entered data, I need the second sheet to display the weekly date (date that is a saturday, which defines the week) and the sum of all things received in that week. This is what I need Sheet 2 to display from user entered data:

```
        11/21/2015  11/28/2015  1/2/2016
Total      22           11         4
Apples      9            2         1
Bananas    10            5         3
Oranges     3            4         0
```

If you can notice, 11/19/2015 and 11/20/2015 falls in the week of 11/21/2015, thus 11/21/2015 is only displayed in one cell, with all things in that week summed. User entered dates can be as far apart as whenever, which is why I included 1/2/2016.

Now, figuring out the formula for the sums should be more simple but the problem I am having is displaying the weekly date once.One of the things that may occur is a user mistakenly enters the same date twice. I checked for this by using the formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(1:1)>=1,0),"CHECK DATES",__________)
```

The first weekly date cell is easy since it responds to the user's first entered date. It is just:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(1:1)>=1,0),"CHECK DATES",B1-weekday(B1)+7)
```

Thus the problem is getting the next date to NOT display 11/21/2015 again.

*UPDATE*
After doing some google searching, my problem is basically the same as finding the k-th largest number than a specified number. Thankfully, there were many websites that gave me useful information. The resulting formula that I came up with to display the weekly dates following the first weekly date is:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MODE.SNGL(1:1)>=1,0),"CHECK DATES",IFERROR(LARGE(1:1,COUNTIF(1:1,">"&B17))-WEEKDAY(LARGE(1:1,COUNTIF(1:1,">"&B17)))+7,""))
```

This formula also allows the cells following the last weekly date to display "", which could be modified to display the #N/A value if wanted. 
Now to move onto the proper summation.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear.
In my original post, that first row is a 'source row', where dates are manually entered, for example, to record when a number of items are received. These dates can be as far apart as whenever. This would be on sheet 1.
Now, on sheet 2 is the weekly dates or dates that end on a saturday, which defines the week. Thus, the reason why I put consecutive dates is such that I only want one cell that displays the weekly date for a corresponding number of dates that falls within that week.
(cont)

Comment: Now, looking at the source row, those dates either fall in the week of 11/21/15 or 11/28/15. Using the source row, I only want those weeks displayed once contiguously on sheet 2. Remember that they are not necessarily consecutive dates; I am only doing that to solve that situation if that ever occurs. At the moment, I have figured this much: =IF(IFERROR(MODE.SINGL(any string of dates),0),"CHECK DATES",_______) . This allows the cell to display check dates IF the person mistakenly wrote the date twice in two cells. (cont)

Comment: The first output cell is easy. Its just the week of the first date. Assuming that the row 1 is for the dates entered by user. Then, =IF(IFERROR(MODE.SINGL(1:1),0),"CHECK DATES",A1-weekday(A1)+7). Going off by the source in OP, this would give 11/21/15. The next cell should display 11/28/15. So the formula for the first week output cell is simpler/different from the second week output cell, which doesnt matter. However, the formula must work from that second cell and on. When the manually entered dates stop, the output cells cant display any more weeks. (cont)

Comment: And thus, when that happens, the rest of the string following the weekly dates can just display the #NA value or "".

Hope I made this more clear now. Maybe a little too clear.

Comment: @fixer1234 not sure if this is how to tag someone

Comment: @fixer1234
Updated with what I believe is necessary information for other people to gain an understanding of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interpreting your question as "I want the value of every seventh cell in a horizontal array starting with the third cell."

If that's the case then you can use the following formula in cell A2 and fill row 2:

```
=INDEX($A1:$J1,1,7*(B1-$A1)-4)
```

Make sure that you:
A: Check that your input data are being recognised as dates not text by excel. You might have to change the dates entered to your local format (e.g. dd/mm/yy) to get it to work.
B: Enlarge the $A1:$J1 range to the full width of your data range.

Comment: Well, no not exactly. They are not necessarily consecutive dates. Please read the comments in response to fixer1234, which I explain concisely what I need the spreadsheet to do.